# Get RFC1123_time in Beanshell ( using JMeter)

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223, rfc1123

Interface need set RFC1123 time in  header 
I can't do it in beanshell using JMeter

I know code works in java:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z",Locale.US);
sdf3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String rfc1123_3 = sdf3.format(new Date());
```

But I can't run it in Beanshell script

Comment: Do you get any error? if so, can you add stacktrace in your question?

Comment: I would also recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead in Java use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You must add import statement in start of your code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Notice that you better move to using JSR223 components over Beanshell

Answer (score 0):

Header:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
```

Code:

```
print(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME));
```

Output:

```
Mon, 3 Jun 2019 13:19:56 GMT
```

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `SimpleDateFormat` that you mentioned is notoriously troublesome and long outdated, you don’t want to use it.

### Links

- [beanshell](https://tio.run/##S0pNzCvOSM3J@Z@ZW5BfVKKQlViWqFeSmZuqp2XNhSGWll@Um1gClPpfUJSZV6Lhn5ZWnFrikliSGgKSzssv14jKz0uFCOuFhjhrQrVowNS4gbklqUV6QW7O8YaGRsbxLo4hrvEhnr6umprW//8DAA) (where above is run; link to beanshell kindly provided by user7294900)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: It's not jshell, you can check it online https://tio.run/#beanshell , see also [Beanshell Vs Jshell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/issues/34)

Comment: Code is still getting error `Class or variable not found: ZoneOffset.UTC` in beanshell, but it works with `JSR223 Sampler`

Comment: Thanks for reporting, @user7294900. It’s interesting, I didn’t get that error. I also don’t when I follow the link at the bottom of my own answer. Wonder if your beanshell is based on an earlier Java version than the one you gave me?